# Dataframe to Kivy Gridlayout - dynamic label updating/reloading

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

Here is my problem: Main working points - Python, Kivy, Pandas

I have a Dataframe which is being displayed as in a Gridlayout, the issue is this data in the dataframe is being updated whilst the app is running and therefore the wrong dataset it being displayed. I had the same issue with some images but you can update images via a simple `.reload()` function and a `Clock.schedule_interval()`.

If you check the Excel sheet you will see I have about 47 row of data.
[This is the excel sheet that gets updated whilst the app is running](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/193OvCxNoSawFCX9RW7NQGlz1mLt71jlT/edit#gid=558856661)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
import pandas as pd
from kivy.clock import Clock

class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.size_hint = (0.9,0.9)
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        self.spacing = 10
        self.bind(minimum_height = self.setter('height'))

    weather_df = pd.read_excel("Weather_data.xlsx")
    self.weather_data_grid = GridLayout(size_hint=(1,None), size=(Window.width, Window.height + 200), row_default_height=15, cols=16)
    #Heading row description
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Clouds'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Cloud Cover Type'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Icons'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Precipication %'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Time'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Temperature'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Fells like Temperature'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Air Pressure'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Humidity'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Dew Point'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='UV Index'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Cloud Coverage %'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Visibility'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Wind Speed'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Wind Direction'))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text='Wind Gusts'))
    #Row 1
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Clouds'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Cloud Cover Type'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Icons'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Precipication %'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Time'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Temperature'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Feels like temp'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Air Pressure'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Humidity'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Dew Point'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'UV Index'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Cloud Coverage'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Visibility'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Wind Speed'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Wind Direction'])))
    self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(weather_df.loc[1,'Wind Gusts'])))

    self.add_widget(self.weather_data_grid)


class SkitouringApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        
        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Info")
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        
        return self.screen_manager
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Skitour_app = SkitouringApp()
    Skitour_app.run()
```

I was also thinking about changing all the rows of Labels in something like this (but if I had to call upon each label by itself to update it like I did with the images, I would have to keep it the way it was up top I guess):

```
self.cloud_grid = GridLayout(row_default_height=15, cols=1)
for i in weather_df['Clouds']:
    clouds = Label(text=str(i))
    self.cloud_grid.add_widget(clouds)

self.weather_data_grid.add_widget(self.cloud_grid)
```

As for the logic I was using to update the images:

```
self.avi_profile_img = Image(source="Data_files\Changing_Data\Outputs\Avi_profile.png")
self.add_widget(self.avi_profile_img)
self.weather_station_img = Image(source="Data_files\Changing_Data\Outputs\Weather_station_3_day.png")
self.add_widget(self.weather_station_img)
Clock.schedule_interval(self.dynamic_img_update,1)

def dynamic_img_update(self, dt):
    self.avi_profile_img.reload()
    self.weather_station_img.reload()
```

Comment: Have you tried using KivyMD's MDDataTable ??(just my opinion)

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks for the suggestion!